# Does mysql encrypt behave differently on INSERT vs UPDATE?

Tags: python, mysql, encryption

I am working on writing a quick REST service to manage email accounts for our domain and have ran into a strange behavior I can't explain.

I am using mysql to authenticate email accounts, and our REST service manages the maildirs and inserts or updates auth credentials using a web interface.  The queries for inserting users as well as updating their passwords both use the `encrypt` mysql command.

What is strange is that inserted users won't work for authentication until the password is changed on the REST interface at least once.  This means that `encrypt` is setting the right value for an update, but something wrong for an insert.

I have tried logging everything in the GET/POST params on the rest service side and it seems like something is going wrong in the database tier.  The REST service logs correct params for passwords at both endpts.  Something in the execution of the queries is different.

My queries look like such (using MySQLdb in Python):

`ADD_USER = "INSERT INTO users (id,name,maildir,crypt) VALUES (%s,%s,%s,encrypt(%s));"`

`CHANGE_PASS = "UPDATE users SET crypt = encrypt(%s) WHERE id=%s"`

Again, `ADD_USER` is entering a bad hash where `CHANGE_PASS` succeeds with the exact same HTTP parameters for `crypt` passed into them (as strings).  Is there any reason why the data tier would do different encryption, or am I barking up the wrong tree?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you use encrypt without salt, it will use a salt based on the current time, so each time you call it, you'll get a different hash:

```
mysql> select encrypt('test');
+-----------------+
| encrypt('test') |
+-----------------+
| 92SErC2PadiaQ   |
+-----------------+

mysql> select encrypt('test');
+-----------------+
| encrypt('test') |
+-----------------+
| A2jgxXgOJx7ls   |
+-----------------+
```

the first two characters (in the standard case) are the salt. if you want to check it, you use the old password as salt, everything but the first two character is ignored:

```
mysql> select encrypt('test', 'A2jgxXgOJx7ls');
+----------------------------------+
| encrypt('test', 'A2jgxXgOJx7ls') |
+----------------------------------+
| A2jgxXgOJx7ls                    |
+----------------------------------+
```

if you want stronger passwords, you havet to use a special salt:

```
mysql> select encrypt('test', '$1$12345678$') as md5;
+------------------------------------+
| md5                                |
+------------------------------------+
| $1$12345678$oEitTZYQtRHfNGmsFvTBA/ |
+------------------------------------+

mysql> select encrypt('test', '$5$0123456789abcdef$') sha256;
+-----------------------------------------------------------------+
| sha256                                                          |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------+
| $5$0123456789abcdef$Wm4jf6bGxEoelzY0H/fTvcw8Qcshq0hyLaRfZWtN8q. |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------+

mysql> select encrypt('test', '$6$0123456789abcdef$') as sha512;
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| sha512                                                                                                     |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| $6$0123456789abcdef$vNATSYYTivQfXwPTUT4q.sRFLs/sgxDXaPipzRlX3WOO4r1NcR.Og5OoU2Cd2agm1WA3pCJ30JU4EKMxpZaDy/ |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

so it all depends on what salt you use. never use unsalted hashes.

Answer (score 1):

First of all: Don't use `ENCRYPT()` for passwords if you can help it. It's kind of limited (for instance: it ignores everything beyond the first 8 characters of a password), and it's not particularly secure, especially because it means that MySQL query logging will log your users' passwords! You'd do much better to do password hashing in Python -- this means not only that MySQL doesn't have to know anything about the actual passwords, but also allows you to use stronger password hashing algorithms.

That all being said, keep in mind that `ENCRYPT()` is not a pure hash function. Its results are not constant unless you pass in a salt as the second argument. How are you checking passwords? A correct solution would look something like:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE <...> AND crypt = ENCRYPT(%s, crypt) ...
```

Or, in Python:

```
row.crypt == crypt.crypt(users_input_password, row.crypt)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  I agree with you.  If I could help it, I wouldn't be using this approach... it's just that we're kind of prisoner to the constraints of how SASLauthd is setup on the remote mail server and don't have the ability to change it.  Can I put the salt into the query like another query param to keep it consistent?  If the salt is omitted, what is used?  Thanks.

Comment: @duskwuff crypt in pyhton is no more or no less secure then encrypt in mysql. it all comes down to how you use it. (of course it may depend on the crypt implementation of the os)

Comment: @mata: It's more secure in that it means that passwords aren't being passed around as much. Like I noted in my answer, if it's passed into MySQL, then MySQL query logging will pick it up (if enabled). If MySQL never sees the password, it can't log it by accident. :)

Comment: @DeaconDesperado: The salt is passed as the second argument to `ENCRYPT()`. If none is specified, MySQL picks one randomly. The salt is stored as the first two characters of the output, so you don't need to store it separately, and you can just pass the hash as the salt (e.g, like I'm doing in the example query) if you're verifying it.

Comment: @duskwuff yea, passing around the password of course is another matter. i just wanted to say that `ENCRYPT` isn't 'bad' because it's inherently weak.